# How to specify regular expression for command arguments in sudoers

Tags: sudo

`sudoers(5)` manpage says that shell-style wildcards (aka meta or glob characters)
could be used in command line arguments in the sudoers file. They are `*`, `?`, `[...]` and `[!...]`.

My idea is to use some stuff in regular expression style, like `/path/to/command -a[v]*`, to mean either `command -a`, `command -av` and `command -avvv...v` in one line (for such commands which changes their's verbosity depending on number of `-v` arguments, e.g. `tcpdump`). But it doesn't works.

Is there some way to do that, not adding `/path/to/command -a -v` several times into `sudoers` with different number of `-v` in each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with [version 1.9.10](https://www.sudo.ws/releases/stable/#1.9.10), the `sudoers` files support POSIX extended regular expressions. According to the manual, you can achieve what you want with:

```
/path/to/command ^-av*$
```

In versions prior to 1.9.10, the `sudoers` man page was fairly clear about not supporting this.  Comments in the man page suggest that it uses the system's `fnmatch()` function to do the matching.  On linux/glibc based systems `fnmatch()` can use an extended globbing format with similar expressiveness to regular expressions but a different syntax.

Therefore if you should be able to rebuild `sudo` to support the extended syntax by finding the place where sudo calls fnmatch adding `FNM_EXTMATCH` to the flags argument and `#define _GNU_SOURCE` to the top of the file that calls it.

Of course if you do this you will be running your own hand patched version of an suid binary so be careful.